# Upgrading nginx 1.10.3 on Debian 9 (stretch) to avoid CVE-2017-7529 vulnerability

Tags: nginx, debian, cve

As of right now Debian 9 (stretch) installs nginx version 1.10.3 which is vulnerable to [CVE-2017-7529](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2017-7529):

> Nginx versions since 0.5.6 up to and including 1.13.2 are vulnerable to integer overflow vulnerability in nginx range filter module resulting into leak of potentially sensitive information triggered by specially crafted request.

I'm concerned for the safety of my users' data, so I'd like to upgrade to the latest version that's no longer affected by this issue.

Comment: I found this here on Google. Just for others who like know: This issue seems to be fixed even for older Debian releases and their nginx package. https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2017-7529

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are multiple ways to obtain nginx 1.13.3 and above. You can compile it yourself, use the [stretch-backports](https://packages.debian.org/stretch-backports/) repository, or you can add nginx's own apt repository. In this answer I will be walking you through the last one as it's probably the easiest to do out of all three.

nginx's website has a [dedicated page](http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html) on how to set up their repository, but there's more to it, especially if you want to avoid this specific vulnerability as of right now. The `stable` branch will install 1.12.0 which is still vulnerable (it was patched in 1.12.1+ and 1.13.3+), so you will need to use `mainline`, which will install 1.13.5.

In the best case scenario switching the nginx version should be as simple as running a few commands and you'll be done in 2-3 minutes with minimal downtime. To be able to get back up and running ASAP, let's start with preparing for the install. First, you need to add the repository to your apt configuration, add the signing key, and update the package list:

```
$ sudo echo "deb http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/debian/ stretch nginx
deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/debian/ stretch nginx" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list
$ wget -qO - https://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key | sudo apt-key add -
$ sudo apt update
```

Next, run the following command:

```
$ sudo apt remove nginx-common
```

This will effectively uninstall nginx from the system, but will preserve your configuration files, save for a systemd service file which is easy to restore.

Next install nginx from the new repository:

```
$ sudo apt install nginx
```

Be aware that this will ask you if you want to replace certain configuration files, like this:

```
Configuration file '/etc/nginx/nginx.conf'
 ==> Modified (by you or by a script) since installation.
 ==> Package distributor has shipped an updated version.
   What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
    Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
    N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
      D     : show the differences between the versions
      Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
*** nginx.conf (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ?
```

Make sure you **don't** enter `Y`, just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or enter `N` each time you're prompted to avoid losing your current configuration.

If you accidentally overwrote your `nginx.conf` you'll - at the very least - need to change the last line in the file from `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;` to `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;` to restore the previous inclusion behavior.

You can verify the newly installed version:

```
$ nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.13.5
```

Finally, you will notice that trying to run `service nginx start` now fails with the following message:

```
Failed to start nginx.service: Unit nginx.service is masked.
```

This is because removing `nginx-common` also wiped `/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service` which was previously used by systemd to manage nginx. To restore this file, simply create it using the command below:

```
$ echo "[Unit]
Description=nginx - high performance web server
Documentation=http://nginx.org/en/docs/
After=network-online.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/var/run/nginx.pid
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
ExecStop=/bin/kill -s TERM $MAINPID

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
" > /lib/systemd/system/nginx.service
```

Finally, run `systemctl unmask nginx` followed by `systemctl enable nginx`, and now you should be able to manage the service just like before, with all your previous settings intact.

```
$ service nginx start
```

Comment: thank you: just used this, in my case I didn't have to recreate `nginx.service` because it wasn't deleted, but the rest of the directions down to the last line on `nginx.conf` are failproof.